# Test DB connection with Python and Postgresql

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, dbconnection

I am trying to connect my database with postgresql and python. I also installed psycopg2 in the same directory in windows and ran the script. But still same error.

```
psycopg2 installed successfully
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts>pip install psycopg2
Collecting psycopg2
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/00/f3/afd8570a32712953c83
e6ba2d3ce3c7cfaa6eeeebf8879da14731445b793/psycopg2-2.8.2-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
Installing collected packages: psycopg2
Successfully installed psycopg2-2.8.2

Execution error
C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\Modern_Times\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/Scripts/db_connect.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/Scripts/db_connect.py", line 1, in <module>
    import psycopg2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I need to test my db connection

Comment: Make sure you have your scripts location added to your system path. It seems like you are having trouble importing psycopg2 module.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a try except and it will throw and error if it fails to connect

```
import psycopg2


def connect__to_database():
    conn = None
    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=your_db_name user=postgres password=your_db_pass")
        return conn 
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print(error)
    return False
```